# Why does Ubuntu 20.04 on ZFS destroy custom datasets at boot-time zpool import of the zpool.cache?

Tags: zfs, cache, history

After creating the targets of a personal data lake, and filling them with plenty of terabytes through `rsync`, I was quite surprised at the next reboot, that Ubuntu's ZFS didn't like the datasets, and automatically destroyed them at the next import.

```
zpool history -il epool
```

```
2020-04-28.23:20:34 [txg:16285] open pool version 5000; software version unknown; uts acacia 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 [on acacia]
2020-04-28.23:20:35 [txg:16287] import pool version 5000; software version unknown; uts acacia 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 [on acacia]
2020-04-28.23:20:40 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN [user 0 (root) on acacia:linux]
2020-04-28.23:30:44 [txg:16409] destroy epool/USERDATA/edata/pub (600)  [on acacia]
...
2020-04-28.23:31:35 [txg:16451] destroy epool/USERDATA/edata/home (702)  [on acacia]
2020-04-28.23:31:38 [txg:16453] destroy epool/USERDATA/edata/data (607)  [on acacia]
2020-04-28.23:31:41 [txg:16455] destroy epool/USERDATA/edata/src (902)  [on acacia]
2020-04-28.23:31:43 [txg:16457] destroy epool/USERDATA/edata (70)  [on acacia]
```

Might it be, that

- the encryption key of the zpool was not loaded yet/anymore, and it was safer to discard the datasets?
- the `zpool.cache` did not get updated at shutdown?
- `zsys`, which previously complained about an unconfigured pool, somehow marked them for disposition?

The zpool itself reports to be in fine shape.

```
zpool status -v epool
```

```
  pool: epool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    epool                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        usb-Seagate_Expansion_Desk_NAAAQA7P-0:0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        usb-Seagate_Expansion_Desk_NAAAQAAR-0:0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

The higher-order datasets without mountpoints survived, too.

```
NAME             USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
epool           22,4M  7,04T      192K  none
epool/USERDATA   192K  7,04T      192K  none
```

There was a warning about a missing association inbetween these two lines when running `apt` commands, but I cannot reproduce the output anymore:

```
INFO Requesting to save current system state      
Successfully saved as "autozsys_q7gdq0"
```

A look into the journal of `zsys-commit` reveals the same complaint about a missing association for the custom dataset after the last reboot, eventually before the destructive action had been initiated; or because of it?

```
root@acacia:~# journalctl -b -3 -u zsys-commit
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-31 19:08:10 CET, end at Wed 2020-04-29 01:45:14 CEST. --
-- No entries --
root@acacia:~# journalctl -b -2 -u zsys-commit
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-31 19:08:10 CET, end at Wed 2020-04-29 01:45:14 CEST. --
Apr 22 23:10:24 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Mark current ZSYS boot as successful...
Apr 22 23:10:25 acacia zsysctl[16934]: INFO Updating GRUB menu
Apr 22 23:10:34 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Mark current ZSYS boot as successful.
Apr 22 23:22:05 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-commit.service: Succeeded.
Apr 22 23:22:05 acacia systemd[1]: Stopped Mark current ZSYS boot as successful.
root@acacia:~# journalctl -b -1 -u zsys-commit
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-31 19:08:10 CET, end at Wed 2020-04-29 01:45:22 CEST. --
Apr 23 00:37:53 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Mark current ZSYS boot as successful...
Apr 23 00:37:54 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Mark current ZSYS boot as successful.
Apr 26 15:11:01 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-commit.service: Succeeded.
Apr 26 15:11:01 acacia systemd[1]: Stopped Mark current ZSYS boot as successful.
root@acacia:~# journalctl -b 0 -u zsys-commit
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-31 19:08:10 CET, end at Wed 2020-04-29 01:45:22 CEST. --
Apr 28 23:20:44 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Mark current ZSYS boot as successful...
Apr 28 23:20:48 acacia zsysctl[3918]: WARNING Couldn't find any association for user dataset epool/USERDATA/edata
Apr 28 23:20:48 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Mark current ZSYS boot as successful.
```

It is the ZSYS garbage collector, which reveals more of the destructive intentions:

```
journalctl -u zsys-gc.service
```

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-31 19:08:10 CET, end at Wed 2020-04-29 01:50:34 CEST. --
Apr 22 23:10:24 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Clean up old snapshots to free space...
Apr 22 23:10:25 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-gc.service: Succeeded.
Apr 22 23:10:25 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Clean up old snapshots to free space.
-- Reboot --
Apr 23 00:47:46 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Clean up old snapshots to free space...
Apr 23 00:47:46 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-gc.service: Succeeded.
Apr 23 00:47:46 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Clean up old snapshots to free space.
Apr 24 22:09:25 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Clean up old snapshots to free space...
Apr 24 22:09:27 acacia zsysctl[7224]: WARNING Couldn't destroy unmanaged user dataset epool/USERDATA/edata: couldn't destroy "epool/USERDATA/edata" and its children: stop destroying dataset on "epool/USERDATA/edata", cannot destroy child: cannot destroy dataset "epool/USERDATA/edata/pub": dataset is busy
Apr 24 22:09:27 acacia zsysctl[7224]: WARNING Couldn't find any association for user dataset epool/USERDATA/edata
Apr 24 22:09:27 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-gc.service: Succeeded.
Apr 24 22:09:27 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Clean up old snapshots to free space.
-- Reboot --
Apr 28 23:30:24 acacia systemd[1]: Starting Clean up old snapshots to free space...
Apr 28 23:30:38 acacia zsysctl[23544]: WARNING Couldn't find any association for user dataset epool/USERDATA/edata
Apr 28 23:31:45 acacia systemd[1]: zsys-gc.service: Succeeded.
Apr 28 23:31:45 acacia systemd[1]: Finished Clean up old snapshots to free space.
```

There is no explicit mention of the destructions here, but we can correlate them with the previous logs.

I understand the risk that is associated with running the system from the experimental ZFS support. Its `bpool` and `rpool` also remained intact. What I am worried about is that user data is destroyed automatically without consent or even explicit notice given. This is neither a sane default nor in any way supportive to the overall ZFS experiment in Ubuntu, and leaves a questionable impression about the implementation quality of the new Canonical ZSYS service.

Eventually it is not ZFS that has to be marked experimental here, as it is rock solid on widespread installations, but the ZSYS integration, that produces the flag.

Where is the place to report this upstream directly at Canonical; some place on Launchpad? I would want to avoid to address the OpenZFS developers primarily, as I consider this an issue of Ubuntu's very own ZFS maintenance and support.

```
missing_300_reputation_for_new_tags: ["zsys", "zpool"]
```

Comment: I am not sure what destroyed your data sets, but it definitely wasn't ZFS itself, nor does it have anything to do with importing by cache. Keys aren't related to this. zpool.cache only helps speed up the import of the pool, it isn't necessary at all, you can export a pool, delete zpool.cache and import it again. zsys I don't know much about but purely by deduction, this is where I would focus my search. If you are looking for snapshot management, I can highly recommend sanoid.

Comment: Yes, ZSYS and the automatic snapshots when running `apt` commands are the only true lead so far.

Comment: This is now filed as https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/103. Let's see what upstream reports back.