# zfs dataset missing after reboot

Tags: encryption, zfs, data-loss

I have a compressed encrypted zfs dataset that seems to have gone completely missing.  There are quite a few google hits for 'zfs missing dataset' or similar, and they're almost always something like the dataset not being automounted, but it is actually still there.  That doesn't seem to be the problem in my case.  I can't see any sign of the dataset, but there is nothing in the history that shows it being destroyed.

```
root@ryzen:~# zpool history epool
History for 'epool':
2020-06-05.18:15:43 zpool create -f -m /extra epool /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD80EFAX-68KNBN0_VDJ8GVBD
2020-06-05.18:17:02 zfs create epool/USERDATA
2020-06-05.18:18:14 zfs set mountpoint=none epool
2020-06-05.18:20:20 zfs create -o mountpoint=/extra/ian epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-06.00:32:47 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2020-06-06.00:44:55 zpool attach epool /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD80EFAX-68KNBN0_VDJ8GVBD /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD80EFAX-68KNBN0_VDJ63U4K
2020-06-07.23:24:31 zfs set compression=on epool
2020-06-07.23:29:21 zfs rename epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn_old
2020-06-07.23:35:23 zfs create -o compression=on -o encryption=on -o keyformat=passphrase epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-07.23:35:45 zfs set mountpoint=/extra/ian2 epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-08.12:32:30 zfs set mountpoint=/extra/ian epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-08.12:34:18 zfs destroy epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn_old
2020-06-14.00:24:11 zpool scrub epool
2020-06-18.17:37:32 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2020-06-18.17:40:31 zfs load-key epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-18.18:47:25 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2020-06-18.18:50:09 zfs load-key epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
2020-06-18.19:26:06 zpool set autoexpand=on epool
2020-06-27.01:18:08 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2020-06-27.02:31:48 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2020-06-27.02:49:49 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
```

This shows the creation of the dataset epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn on a mirrored pool.  Then I filled it with some stuff.  After that I thought I should make it encrypted and compressed, so I renamed it, made another encrypted & compressed data set, copied the files over, and destroyed the original.  Thereafter everything was working fine, you can see a couple of times where the system was rebooted and I reloaded the key.  Last night I did another kernel upgrade and some minor tweaks to the BIOS configuration that required rebooting a couple of additional times.  And now the dateset epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn has gone:

```
root@ryzen:~# zfs load-key epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn
cannot open 'epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn': dataset does not exist

root@ryzen:~# zfs list 
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                              750M  1.02G       96K  none
bpool/BOOT                                         746M  1.02G       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xqma33                           746M  1.02G      196M  /boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xqma33/grub                     16.6M  1.02G     7.46M  /boot/grub
epool                                             29.1M  7.04T      104K  none
epool/USERDATA                                      96K  7.04T       96K  none
rpool                                              569G  1.19T      192K  none
rpool/ROOT                                         254G  1.19T      192K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xqma33                           254G  1.19T     25.0G  /
....

root@ryzen:~# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool  1.88G   750M  1.14G        -         -     5%    39%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
epool  7.27T  29.8M  7.27T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
rpool  1.80T   569G  1.25T        -         -    13%    30%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

The zpool list shows that there is only a few MB allocated in the pool, whereas there should be a few TB.  I can get most of the stuff back, since this is a recent hard-drive upgrade and I still have the old hard-drive, BUT I used ZFS with mirrored disks precisely so that I would never have to worry about data-loss again (for a reasonable definition of 'never').  So this is very scary that I seem to have lost my data.  Does anyone know what has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve just run into the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. In my instance though, the encrypted dataset disappeared after a forced shutdown due to a system lock up.

I’ve found that when I run a “zpool history -i poolname” to get more detail, where “poolname” was the pool containing the encrypted dataset - the encrypted dataset was explicitly destroyed at some point!

So check yours as well. Given this was an explicit destroy, I don’t believe this is a ZFS bug but rather an Ubuntu 20.04 bug. I’m still investigating but I think some boot time service is cleaning up data sets for some improper reason in this scenario.

EDIT: it appears others have run into the issue in recent months. Ubuntu’s Zsys is suspected. See this answer and comments for more information: [Why does Ubuntu 20.04 on ZFS destroy custom datasets at boot-time zpool import of the zpool.cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232637/why-does-ubuntu-20-04-on-zfs-destroy-custom-datasets-at-boot-time-zpool-import-o)

EDIT again: just in case, to maybe save you some time - we definitely ran into this bug https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/103, which has sense been closed for reasons. In both our cases it wasn’t that the dataset was encrypted but apparently just that it was in the USERDATA dataset. I’ll have to read more, but this does not seem sane to me.

Comment: Thanks - yes "zpool history -i epool" shows an entry:
`2020-06-27.01:27:37 [txg:336415] destroy epool/USERDATA/ian_i01gxn (783)`

It seems to be a naming convention problem - I called it USERDATA simply for consistency, I didn't realize this would be a problem.  I'm new to ZFS and Ubuntu's tools; I didn't know about the distinction between managed and unmanaged datasets either.